# React/Redux - Change local state or change redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using React and Redux to populate a user list. My component list all users from the redux store (the data is coming from a mongodb db, incase if you are curious). There is a checkbox to select-all users in the list, which upon checking should mark all checkboxes against all users. I think there are two approaches to do this.

1. Use a local-state (using useState hook) and dump all users in that state and then .map the user list. Clicking on "select all" checkbox will add a "is_checked" field for each users and during iteration check the user checkboxes only if the "is_checked" field is true.
2. Change the redux state and add the "is_checked" flag and do the rest as explain in point #1. (i dont think we should mutate the state)

Please advise.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const UserComponent = () => {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users["users"]);

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="allUsers">
        <input type="checkbox" /> Select All Users
      </label>

      {users.map((user) => (
        <div key={user.id}>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          {user.name}
          {user.email}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a third approach which would allow you to achieve what you are looking for, and avoid to *taint* the redux user store.

In fact, the users stored in redux serve as data cache for server values.

If at some point you need to send back a user value to an API, mutating that  cache would introduce extraneous properties to those objects, which is not
very clean. Basically you will have a mix of server and client UI concerns.

---

***My suggestion is as follow***:

1. Do no change the redux store with regards to how it stores the user values on the client.
2. Introduce a client-only state, called `selectedUsers` which would contain an array or a set of user ID.

Code would be as follow:

(untested, just pseudo js code)

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const UserComponent = () => {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users["users"]);
  const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState([]);
  const allUsersSelected = selectedUsers.length === users.length

  const toggleAllSelected = () => 
    setSelectedUsers(val => val ? [] : users.map(u => u.id))

  const makeHandleToggleUser = id => ev => 
    setSelectedUsers(val => {
      // if val includes id, return array less id
      // otherwise return [...val, id]
    } 

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="allUsers">
        <input type="checkbox" checked={allUsersSelected} onClick={toggleAllSelected} /> Select All Users
      </label>

      {users.map((user) => (
        <div key={user.id}>
          <input type="checkbox" onClick={makeHandleToggleUser(id)} checked={allUsersSelected || selectedUsers.includes(user.id)} />
          {user.name}
          {user.email}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

*Note: of if that selection needs to be made available to other components, you can perfectly put this value in redux instead of the component state, and use actions/selectors accordingly*

Answer (score 0):

It would be more convenient to add an `isSelected` boolean for each user in the Redux store. So when you are setting the users list in the store, you can map it into a new array, add an `isSelected` field to each user, which defaults to `false`.

You will need to add an action to update the value of this flag from your component.